# How do I replace [ with \[ on matching lines?

Tags: sed, perl

How can I replace `[` with `\[` in multiple lines, where there may be multiple occurrences per line, but only do it on lines that start with `ABCD`?

Comment: post the sample data and the final expected result

Comment: Although I've edited this to make it clearer, I definitely suggest that you **[edit]** this again to include sample input and output as RomanPerekhrest requested. That should make clear exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

In `sed`:

```
sed '/^ABCD/ s/\[/\\[/g' filename
```

The expression is an address followed by a command. The address, `/^ABCD/`, means the command will only be executed when the line matches the regular expression `^ABCD` (lines that start with `ABCD`).

The command, `s/\[/\\[/g`, means replace all occurrences of `[` with `\[`. In general, the command is of the form `s/foo/bar/`, which means replace regular expression `foo` with `bar`. The `g` at the end makes it match multiple times per line, and since `[` and `\` both have special functions in regular expressions, they're escaped in the command -- `\[` means a literal `[`, while `\\[` means a literal `\[`.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly this is correct:

```
perl -nle 'if ( /^ABCD/) { $_ =~ s/\[/\\[/g;};print'
```

(Perl beginner here...)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've input file like this:

```
$ cat input.txt
ABCD this line [ starts with [ abcd
this one doesn't
ABCD but this [ one does
```

Since your question is tagged with Perl, here's one:

```
$ perl -pe '/^ABCD/ and s/\[/\\[/g' input.txt                                                         
ABCD this line \[ starts with \[ abcd
this one doesn
ABCD but this \[ one does
```

`-p` will allow assuming implicit loop and automatic printing, much like `sed` does, and the actual code will do the replacement job if line read starts with `ABCD`.

---

We can do it in awk like so:

```
$ awk '/^ABCD/{gsub(/\[/,"\\[")};1' input.txt                                                         
ABCD this line \[ starts with \[ abcd
this one doesn't
ABCD but this \[ one does
```

This works in a fairly simple way: 
- if line starts with `ABCD`, `gsub()` will do the replacement.
- since awk code works on the `evaluation { actions}` structure, the `1` is simply forcing an evaluation that is "true" on each line, and with `{ actions}` part omitted, it will default to printing; basically, a small hack for making things shorter instead of doing `{print}`

---

And because why not, here's python:

```
$ python -c 'import sys; print "\n".join([i.strip().replace("[","\[") if i.startswith("ABCD") else i.strip() for i in sys.stdin ])' < input.txt                                                                                 
ABCD this line \[ starts with \[ abcd
this one doesn't
ABCD but this \[ one does
```

This also works in fairly simple way:

- we redirect the text into python's `stdin` stream via `<` shell operator.
- all lines are read and processed within `[ item for item in iterable]` structure - this is known as list comprehension; we basically built up a list of all lines
- `i.strip().replace("[","\[") if i.startswith("ABCD") else i.strip()` is farily straight forward - we trim trailing newline, and if the line starts with "ABCD" - replace all `[` with `\[`, otherwise - just a stripped original line
- once we've read all lines into list, that list of lines will be rejoined into one new-line separated string, and printed.

And in script form this would be as so:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as fd: 
    for i in fd:
        print i.strip().replace("[","\[") if i.startswith("ABCD") else i.strip()
```

and works as so:

```
$ ./add_slash.py input.txt                                                             
ABCD this line \[ starts with \[ abcd
this one doesn
ABCD but this \[ one does
```